# Fill a DE thanks to SSJS in Script Activity using an external API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, ssjs, automationstudio

What I'm trying to do, is to fill a Data Extension using SSJS on weather column.
(For the test I'm using nodeJS)

**Data Extension : "Weather API"**

```
weather  |     city name       |  country code

(empty)  |     Bordeaux        |     FR
(empty)  |      Bréval         |     FR
(empty)  |     Brussels        |     BE
(empty)  |    Flers, Orne      |     FR
(empty)  |     Frankfurt       |     DE
(empty)  |  Grandville, Aube   |     FR
(empty)  |      Le Havre       |     FR
(empty)  |      London         |     GB
(empty)  |    Los Angeles      |     US
```

> I'm using the following API : https://openweathermap.org/api

Here is my code :

```
const https = require('https');
var cities = [
    {cityName: 'Bordeaux',countryCode: 'FR'},
    {cityName: 'Breval',countryCode: 'FR'},
    {cityName: 'Brussels',countryCode: 'BE'},
    {cityName: 'Flers, Orne',countryCode: 'FR'},
    {cityName: 'Frankfurt',countryCode: 'DE'},
    {cityName: 'Grandville, Aube',countryCode: 'FR'},
    {cityName: 'Le Havre',countryCode: 'FR'},
    {cityName: 'London',countryCode: 'GB'},
    {cityName: 'Los Angeles',countryCode: 'US'},
]
let APIKey = '...........................'
var timesRun = 0;
var tmpDataObj = []
const targetDataExtension = DataExtension.Init("Weather API");
const interval = setInterval(function(){
    https.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q="+cities[timesRun].cityName+","+cities[timesRun].countryCode+"&units=metric&APPID="+APIKey, (resp) => {
        let data = '';
        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', () => {
            let global = JSON.parse(data)
            let weather = global.list[global.list.length - 1].weather[0].main
            let weatherObj = {
                cityName: global.city.name,
                weather: weather
            }
            tmpDataObj.push(weatherObj)
            console.log(tmpDataObj);
            timesRun += 1;
            if(timesRun === cities.length){
                clearInterval(interval);
                for (let i = 0; i < tmpDataObj.length; i++) {
                    targetDataExtension.Rows.Update({"weather":tmpDataObj[i].weather}, ["city name"],[tmpDataObj[i].cityName]);
                }
            }
        });
    })
}, 2000);
```

Here is what I retrieve on my terminal :

```
➜  test node aaaa.js
{ cityName: 'Bordeaux', weather: 'Rain' }
{ cityName: 'Breval', weather: 'Rain' }
{ cityName: 'Brussels', weather: 'Clouds' }
{ cityName: 'Flers', weather: 'Clear' }
{ cityName: 'Frankfurt', weather: 'Clouds' }
{ cityName: 'Grandville', weather: 'Rain' }
{ cityName: 'Le Havre', weather: 'Clear' }
{ cityName: 'London', weather: 'Clear' }
{ cityName: 'Los Angeles', weather: 'Clear' }
➜  test |
```

So at this point everything is OK for me. But when run this code on **Script Activity** in **Automation Studio** nothing append ... I have no idea why.
This is my first time using Script Activity.

Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: SFMC's SSJS is pretty ancient ([ES3](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_syntaxGuide.htm)) so while the test code works in Node.js, it most likely won't translate over to SFMC. I would try getting your code to run successfully first in a one-off landing page (CloudPages) or test email preview before copying/pasting the code directly into a script activity.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! Do you know any documentation on ES3 ? thxx

Comment: It's [pretty dense](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf), so your best bet would be to go through the SFMC-specific SSJS docs instead: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_serverSideJavaScript.htm

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MarkG, but one thing I noticed is that you are using `JSON.parse()`. With SSJS, you should use `Platform.Function.ParseJSON()`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformUtilityParseJSON.htm

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! ```Platform.Function.ParseJSON()``` is specific to Salesforce ?

Comment: Yes the Platform library provides functions to access Salesforce Marketing Cloud features. As mentioned previously Node != Salesforce SSJS, you will need to use only ES3 features. You can't use `let`, `const`, and JSON methods aren't ES3. Review the [Salesforce SSJS documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_syntaxGuide.htm)